# mysql_query error on db class

Tags: php, mysql

i'm try to write simple user registeration page and use simple DBCONNECTOR Class same as below and when i try to send user to database i get mysql_query() error.this is my php code and class please help me to fix problem

and this is my dbconnector class:

```
<?php
    require_once 'UConfig.inf.php';
    class udbcl extends USettings{
        var $link;
        var $myquery;
        function UDbconnect(){
            $DBinfo=USettings::GSettings();
            $DBhost=$DBinfo['UDbhost'];
            $DBname=$DBinfo['UDbname'];
            $DBusername=$DBinfo['UDbusername'];
            $DBpassword=$DBinfo['UDbpassword'];
            $this->link=mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBusername,$DBpassword);
            mysql_select_db($DBname);

        }
      function UQuery($myquery){
          $this->link=$myquery;
          return mysql_query($myquery,  $this->link);

      }
      function UFetch($result){
         return mysql_fetch_array($result);
      }
      function UDbclose(){
          mysql_close($this->link);

      }
    }

?>
```

and this is my register.php page :

```
<?php
require_once ('UConfig/UDbconnector.php');
$myinfoadd = new udbcl();
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $myq = "INSERT INTO userinfo(username,password,email,telphon) VALUES('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[telnumber]')";
    $myinfoadd->UQuery($myq);
    $myinfoadd->UDbclose();
    echo "You registration is Success!";
    sleep(3);
    header('Location:index.php');
} else {
    print <<<hldoc
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>U S R R</title></head><body><form method="POST" action="register.php" ><b>User Name:</b> <input type="text" name="username" /><br/><b>User Password:</b><input type="password" name="password" /><br/><b>User Email:</b><input type="email" name="email" /><br/><b>User Tel:</b><input type="telnumber" name="telnumber" /><br/><input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/></form></body></html>
hldoc;
}
?>
```

When I try to register user I get an error same as below:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\uzu\UConfig\UDbconnector.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\uzu\UConfig\UDbconnector.php on line 25
>
> You registration is Success!
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\uzu\UConfig\UDbconnector.php:18) in C:\xampp\htdocs\uzu\register.php on line 10

Comment: So where exactly do you call `UDbconnect`?  And why are you resetting the class variable `$this->link` (a resource) to `$myquery` (a string), and thus overwriting its original value with every call to `UQuery`?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: You're setting `$this->link` to the query you pass, which is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function UQuery($myquery){
    $this->link=$myquery;
    return mysql_query($myquery,  $this->link);
}
```

The above function is equivalent to:

```
function UQuery($myquery){
    $this->link=$myquery;
    return mysql_query($myquery,  $myquery);
}
```

Don't re-assign `$this->link` and you should be fine.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed you never initialize the link. You should do this in the class constructor, or pass it as a parameter *into* the constructor.

```
class udbcl extends USettings{
    var $link;
    var $myquery;

    public function __construct($dbLink = null) {
        if (is_null($dbLink)) {
            $dbLink = $this->UDbconnect();
        }
        $this->link = $dbLink;
    } 

    private function UDbconnect(){
        $DBinfo=USettings::GSettings();
        $DBhost=$DBinfo['UDbhost'];
        $DBname=$DBinfo['UDbname'];
        $DBusername=$DBinfo['UDbusername'];
        $DBpassword=$DBinfo['UDbpassword'];
        $this->link=mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBusername,$DBpassword);
        mysql_select_db($DBname);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```